# finite number of $p$-elements will generate a $p$-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that finite number of $p$-elements will generate a $p$-group?

I dont think so, as if order of  $x,y$ are powers of $p$, then order of $xy$ may not be. I cant think of a counterexample.

Comment: Your guess is right. Try multiplying two $p$-cycles in a symmetric group. Sometimes you'll get an element of order $p$, but often enough you won't.

Comment: If the $p$-group is not finitely generated then it cannot be generated by a finite number of elements.

Comment: A simple counterexample is the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ for $n$ not a power of two: this group is generated by two elements of order 2.

Comment: Most finite simple groups are generated by three involutions and give thus counterexamples.